# TypeScript Compiler Options for strict code compliance beyond strict mode

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

We would like to configure TSC hopefully with a command line option to generate errors when developers declare class fields using implicit type expressions instead of explicit see code below.

```
class Appliance {
    //coding style we want to enforce:
    private _group:Group = new Group(); 

    //coding style we want to prevent by issuing error:
    private _group = new Group(); 

    //coding style we want to enforce as it does not rely only on
    //constructor parameters list for declaration 
    public assetTag:EquipmentTag; 

    public constructor(assetTag:AssetTag, 
        //coding style we want to prevent by issuing error if
        //no explicit declaration above constructor
        supplier:Company) {

        this.assetTag = assetTag; //coding style we want to enforce
    }

}
```

We use strict mode for TSC but it still allows for some casual coding style as shown.

Is there any TSC option we can use to go beyond strict mode and enforce some coding style compliance?

Comment: These seem more like something tslint/eslint (which is recommended for new projects) could enforce, either through an existing rule (I think one exists to force type annotations on everything) or through custom rules. The compiler itself is not customizable

Answer (score 0):

Just as Titian suggested, code style is enforced by ts-lint https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

The Rule you are looking for: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/